# why can't I install Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library

Tags: android, sdk, cloud

I'm following the instruction about using gcm here http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html, and I'm stuck at the following step:

**Install the Helper Libraries**
To perform the steps described in the following sections, you must first install the helper libraries (reference: client and server). From the SDK Manager, **install Extras > Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library**. This creates a gcm directory under YOUR_SDK_ROOT/extras/google/ containing these subdirectories: gcm-client, gcm-demo-appengine, gcm-demo-client, gcm-demo-server, and gcm-server.

In my SDK manager, I can't find the option: Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library, as I captured in this screenshot [image], what I should do to resolve this? Thanks

Comment: Found a similar issue a which worked for Android Studio [1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21678951/google-cloud-messaging-for-android-library-not-found-in-the-sdk-manager/23092848#23092848

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this same issue. You must update EVERYTHING else in the Eclipse plug-in before GCM will show up. Force an update from the sdk manager and it will show up once the version is current.

Comment: CAn you explain this post in detail or any screen images

Answer (score 3):

Use the *Android SDK Manager* to update your SDK to r20, after which you'll also need to update your Eclipse plugin. You'll then find the *Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library* under Extras in the SDK manager, along with everything else. Just select what you want to install.

And if following error comes :- *android sdk manager nothing was installed*

Then

1. Go to the folder where android-sdk resides.
2. Right click on SDK Manager and select run as administrator.
3. Restart eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

1. Run Eclipse
2. Go Eclipse  Menu  :: 
   Help >> Install New Software
3. in the Install Window setting like this
   If youe select "Work with " list box  ADT Site 
     :: my case is like that "ADT Site - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse"
   Check all

   - Develop  Tools
   - NDK Plugins
     and Next and finish...
4. Now go to "Android SDK Manager" window 
   You will see in "Extras" category  and "Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library"