# Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library not Found in the sdk Manager

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to implement a push notification solution for android.I am following the steps given in the following tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

but when i tried to install the Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library using the android sdk(i am using the latest sdk) i don't find it the extras module like you can see in this picture

[image]

This is really strange.
Is there any solution?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Install Google Play Services Library

[image]

For client side implementation of GCM use this [link](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/)

For server side purposes follow the tutorial

Pls note that the tutorial explains how you can send messages to individual devices using the registration id and not to all devices at one go.

**[Update]**

I observed that still some people are using the deprecated library - GCM for android.

"Google Cloud Messaging for Android" is deprecated and no more used.GCM API's are now available as part of "Google Play Services".

Eventhough @anubhav's answer is correct for the asked question it is not recommended.

Answer (score 69):

Select the 'Show Obsolete Packages' option in Packages menu and you will be able to view it and install.

[image]

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer, or correct answer should be integrated/updated with this answer

Comment: This is deprecated. People, don't use this as rightly pointed out by [@HAR](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21684487/1276636)

Answer (score 7):

Seems like this package is now obsolete. In order to see it in SDK Manager I had to check "Show obsolete packages" in the "Packages" menu

**Edit (clarification of my answer)**

I encountered this problem when trying to run `Maven Android SDK Deployer`. The version of the SDK deployer I used, was expecting gcm package installed (at least when running the deployer in  its default configuration).

For other purposes, it's recommended to use the newer `Google Play Services` instead, as stated in one of the answers here.

Answer (score 3):

### To Add Google Play Services to Your Project (For Android Studio)

1. Open the build.gradle (Module:app) file inside your application module directory.
2. Add a new build rule under dependencies for the latest version of play-services.

For example:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

3.Save the changes and click **Sync Project with Gradle Files** in the toolbar.

4.Open your app's manifest file and add the following tag as a child of the `<application>` element:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

go here for more details :[Setting up google play services](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Setup)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any solution?

Use something newer than that tutorial. The old GCM API was deprecated last May and [was replaced with a new one](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).

Comment: but where do i find the gcm.jar file?

Comment: @HadjAliOussama: The legacy `gcm.jar` file is no longer published by Google. The new API uses the new Play Services SDK, not that JAR.

Answer (score 1):

Just tick the "**Obsolete**" checkbox in Android SDK Manager popup.

Answer (score 1):

the Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library is obsolete,you can find it by do this: sdk manager --> packages(left corner)-->show obsolete packages,then you will see it.but google sugessts to use Googleplay Service  instead.